# How to disable "swipe to go back" in Microsoft Edge with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, microsoft-edge

I'm currently working on a website with Object horizontal rotation features. So let's say the first image you see is the front of an object, then the second image is the side and the third the back, the fourth the other side and the fifth the front view again.

In my case, I have in total 24 images of an object, which means there's a 15 degree angle difference between each picture.
Right now I'm trying to make the rotation more smooth. It works perfectly on any browsers if I use my mouse. However, things start to go wrong if i use my touchscreen instead for browsers like Microsoft Edge.

The problem on Edge is that, if I try to swipe the object to the right, it somehow triggers the "**go back to previous page**" feature in **Edge**. It's something I could fix with simple javascript code when I'm using **Chrome**. The code looks like this:

```
        $(".reel-holder").bind('touchstart', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Another problem when swiping on Edge is that, the rotation is rotated by picture. No matter how I swipe on the touch screen, it only goes to the next/previous picture.

How can I fix this problem with Javascript/JQuery?

iS THIS EGG

Comment: You need to show us what you have. Without the ability to `console.log()` and `console.trace()` it, we cannot help much. Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) CSS property. For each element whose gestures you want to prevent Edge from handling, set `touch-action` to `none`. Alternatively, you could set `touch-action` to `none` on a common ancestor, or, if you want to prevent Edge from handling any gesture, set it on the `body`.

If you only want to prevent Edge from going back to the previous page, by swiping, but want Edge to handle other gestures, you could set `touch-action` to `pan-right pan-y pinch-zoom`.

Example:

```
.reel-holder {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

Comment: No idea why this answer got down-voted. touch-action is how you control the behavior.

Comment: @cleong Thanks, I didn't understand either. The only thing that may have caused confusion was that I referred to 'the browser' instead of 'Edge', before the edit, so the downvoter might have thought I meant it worked for all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS this worked for me

I used

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overscroll-behavior: contain;    
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior